# How to show image from database into a dynamically created table using code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

I have an image database where i upload all of my images. Now i want to show my images in my view page into a 4*4 table. that means i want to view 16 images at a time with pagination. but i face a problem i can view only 13 images and i can print 3 rows out of 4, last row is started but not ended what's the problem? (sorry for my weak English)

Here is my view Code:

```
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($designimages as $designimage){
    if ($j == 0) { ?>
        <tr>
        <?php $j = 1; ?>
    <?php }
    if ($i < 4) { ?>            
        <td> <img id="content2" src="<?php echo base_url($designimage->album_thumb) ;?>" alt="" width="155" height="155" /> </td>
        <?php $i++ ;?>
    <?php   }
    else {
        $j = 0;
        $i = 0;
    ?>
        </tr>
    <?php   } ?>

    <?php } ?>
    </table>
    <?php   
    if(isset($pagination))echo $pagination;
    ?>
```

Comment: can you provide us more detail? I am not able to get your question properly. Is there any problem in pagination i.e pagination giving only 13 results instead of 16 on single page? or your view is not been properly displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **get()**, you can use **get_paged_iterated()**

From the Datamapper doc:  http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getalt.html#get_paged

> Each call sets the following properties on an object, which is called $paged by default.
>
> If you already have a field called paged, you can easily change the object to a different name with the last argument.
>
> total_rows: The total number of rows in the unpaged query.
>
> total_pages: The total number of pages, based on $page_size.
>
> current_page: The current page (usually passed in).
>
> current_row: The first row on the current page.
>
> last_row: The first row on the last page.
>
> has_previous: If TRUE, there are previous pages in the query.
>
> previous_page: The previous page or 1, whichever is greater.
>
> previous_row: The previous page's first row or 0, whichever is greater.
>
> has_next: If TRUE, there are more pages in the query.
>
> next_page: The next page or total_pages, whichever is less.
>
> next_row: The next page's first row or last_row, whichever is less.
>
> page_size: Number of items per page, might be useful for the view.
>
> items_on_page: Number of items on the current page, i.e., $object->result_count().

Example from the doc:

```
    // IN THE CONTROLLER
    function archive($page = 1)
    {
        $posts = new Post();
        // show newest first
        $posts->order_by('created', 'DESC');
        // show 10 posts per page
        $posts->get_paged($page, 10);

        // send to view
        $this->load->view('posts/archive', array('posts' => $posts));
    }

    // IN THE VIEW
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
        // render the post
    }
    if($posts->paged->has_previous)
    {
        ?>
    <a href="<?= site_url('posts/archive/1' ?>">&lt;&lt; First</a>
    <a href="<?= site_url('posts/archive/'.$posts->paged->previous_page) ?>">&lt; Prev</a>
        <?
    }
    if($posts->paged->has_next)
    {
        ?>
    <a href="<?= site_url('posts/archive/'.$posts->paged->next_page ?>">Next &gt;</a>
    <a href="<?= site_url('posts/archive/'.$posts->paged->total_pages) ?>">Last &gt; &gt;</a>
        <?
    }
```